# Formulas for Optimizing Celery Configurations

Tags: python, django, heroku, redis, celery

I'm trying to figure out celery, and most of the configurations I've landed on have been from guesswork and monitoring jobs/performance after I update settings.

A couple of interesting observations -

I have continued to see a redis error `ConnectionError('max number of clients reached',)`. It has happened when I have added more periodic tasks. The confusing part about this is my redis plan has a max of 40 connections. In my django app I configured celery to allow for 20 as the max amount of redis connections. Some of the configurations can be found below.

```
CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 20
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True   


CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    "fanout_prefix": True,  
    "fanout_patterns": True,    
    "max_connections": 10,  
    "socket_keepalive": True,   
}
```

I finally upgraded Celery, Redis, and Celery Beat, and removed the above configurations. I have not seen the same issue since.

```
celery-redbeat==0.13.0 --> celery-redbeat==1.0.0
celery==4.3.0 --> celery==4.4.4
redis==3.3.11 --> redis==3.5.3
```

So after this upgrade my connection errors have gone away for now. I notice in my redis instance that the number of connections has almost halved from a daily average of 39, to 24.

The next error I tackle is r14 errors where I'm going over my memory limit. I fix this by setting `--concurency=4` It was defaulting to 8. No more r14s as of now. What confuses me - I thought celeries default settings prevented these issues, like it chose concurrency based on the number of cores on the machine processing the task.

So TLDR -

I have 1 celery worker, 2 queues, I know the amount of periodic tasks I am running and how many overall jobs.

With the above information, are there formulas I can use to determine things like `concurrency`, `redis_max_connections`, `broker_pool_limit` and other optimizations that will take a lot of the guessing out of what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply - no. There is no formula that would be useful with all combinations of Celery configuration options.

Furthermore, concurrency setting for an example heavily depends on the type of your tasks. If the tasks are computationally intensive, then it makes no sense to set concurrency to anything higher then number of CPU cores. If not, then you may even multiply by 10, depending how much CPU your tasks use.

Same with regards to the Redis max connections and broker pool limit - you rarely need anything else but the defaults, *however*, if you have hundreds of workers (not worker processes) then you may have connection problems, so you may actually need to tweak these numbers.